# how to view sql query horizontally using pivot from 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server

table.[image: table]

rows of my table. for january

[image: january result]

rows for february

[image: february result]

My sample query

```
select id2,
(select budget from tblmonth where id2='1' and month='January' and groups='CCARE') as jbud1,
(select actual from tblmonth where id2='1' and month='January' and groups='CCARE') as jact1,
(select variance from tblmonth where id2='1' and month='January' and groups='CCARE') as jvar1,
(select [percent] from tblmonth where id2='1' and month='January' and groups='CCARE') as jper1,

(select budget from tblmonth where id2='2' and month='February' and groups='CCARE') as fbud2,
(select actual from tblmonth where id2='2' and month='February' and groups='CCARE') as fact2,
(select variance from tblmonth where id2='2' and month='February' and groups='CCARE') as fvar2,
(select [percent] from tblmonth where id2='2' and month='February' and groups='CCARE') as fper2


 from tblmonth where groups='CCARE' and id2='1' and month='January'
```

my problem with this query is it returns duplicate values.
[image: duplicate]

i want to achieve is.

the columns budget, actual, variance, percent from each month will be this display in a single result. like this in the image.

[image: want to achieved]

thanks in advance :) im only new to sql and im using a sql server 2014.

Comment: Have you tried to distinct your set? `select distinct id2, ...`

Comment: hi @sqluser I'd tried distinct the result is also duplicate like the picture above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I create temp table, similar to yours:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblmonth (
    id2 smallint,
    [year] varchar(50), 
    groups varchar(100), 
    element varchar(100), 
    [month] varchar(50), 
    budget decimal(18,2),
    actual decimal(18,2),
    variance decimal(18,2),
    [percent] decimal(18,2),
)

INSERT INTO #tblmonth VALUES
(1, 2016, 'CCARE', 'Basic', 'January', 52.28, 43.00, 43.98, 0.00),
(2, 2016, 'CCARE', 'Bonuses', 'January', 1.77, 17.10, -46.12, 0.00),
(3, 2016, 'CCARE', 'Overtime', 'January', 2.34, 20.20, 7.98, 0.00),
(4, 2016, 'CCARE', 'Comminication', 'January', 19.01, 27.34, -81.98, 0.00),
(5, 2016, 'CCARE', 'HDMF', 'January', 0.98, 22.17, -22.98, 0.00),
(1, 2016, 'CCARE', 'Basic', 'February', 152.28, 3.00, 4.98, 0.00),
(2, 2016, 'CCARE', 'Bonuses', 'February', 12.77, 1.10, -4.12, 0.00),
(3, 2016, 'CCARE', 'Overtime', 'February', 23.34, 3.20, 0.98, 0.00),
(4, 2016, 'CCARE', 'Comminication', 'February', 191.01, 2.34, -1.98, 0.00),
(5, 2016, 'CCARE', 'HDMF', 'February', 10.98, 2.17, -2.98, 0.00)
```

Then I ran dynamic SQL + UNPIVOT + PIVOT (about pivoting you can read on [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) and [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-pivoting-data-in-sql-server-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @columns nvarchar(max)
--here we get column names for pivoting, so we dont need to write them by hand
SELECT @columns = STUFF((
    SELECT ',budget'+[MONTH] + ',actual'+[MONTH]+ ',variance'+[MONTH]+',percent'+[MONTH]
    FROM #tblmonth 
    GROUP BY [MONTH]
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

-- Main query, at first we UNPIVOT so we make column to rows,
-- then we pivot them back in a way we need.
SELECT @sql = '
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  [year], 
            groups, 
            element, 
            [rows] + [month] as [rowname],
            [values]
    FROM (
        SELECT  id2,
                [year],
                groups,
                element,
                [month],
                CAST(budget as varchar(50)) as budget,
                CAST(actual as varchar(50)) as actual,
                CAST(variance as varchar(50)) as variance,
                CAST([percent] as varchar(50)) as [percent]
        FROM #tblmonth) as p
    UNPIVOT (
        [values] FOR [rows]
        IN (budget, actual, variance, [percent])
    ) as unpvt
    ) as p
PIVOT(
    MAX([values]) FOR [rowname] IN ('+@columns+'
)
)  as pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Output:

```
year    groups  element         budgetFebruary  actualFebruary  varianceFebruary    percentFebruary budgetJanuary   actualJanuary   varianceJanuary percentJanuary
2016    CCARE   Basic           152.28          3.00            4.98                0.00            52.28           43.00           43.98           0.00
2016    CCARE   Bonuses         12.77           1.10            -4.12               0.00            1.77            17.10           -46.12          .00
2016    CCARE   Comminication   191.01          2.34            -1.98               0.00            19.01           27.34           -81.98          0.00
2016    CCARE   HDMF            10.98           2.17            -2.98               0.00            0.98            22.17           -22.98          0.00
2016    CCARE   Overtime        23.34           3.20            0.98                0.00            2.34            20.20           7.98            0.00
```

Comment: thanks for this il' try this as soon as possible and feedback :).

Comment: hi @gofr1, may i ask if i can put the where function inside the pivot example "where groups='CCARE'"

Comment: Hi @gofr1, do you have any reference that i can read or study using unpivot and pivot functions

Comment: I add links to my answer. One is from MSDN, another is with more explanations.

Comment: thanks @gofr1 for the link, so i can understand better about pivoting :)

Comment: thank you @gofr1 for this pivot. ill be doing more practice and study about the pivot

Comment: My pleasure! Great that it helps and you found something new to learn! :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this :

```sql
 select 
   q.id2, q.year, q.groups, q.element, 
   jan.month as jMonth, jan.budget as jBudget, jan.actual as jActual, jan.variance as jVariance, jan.[percent] as jPercent, jan.date_update as jDateUpdate,
   feb.month as fMonth, feb.budget as fBudget, feb.actual as fActual, feb.variance as fVariance, feb.[percent] as fPercent, feb.date_update as fDateUpdate
 from (select groups, year, id2, element from tblmonth 
       where groups='CCARE' and year=2016 group by groups, year, id2, element) q
 left join (select * from tblmonth 
            where groups='CCARE' and year=2016 and month='January') jan
   on (q.groups = jan.groups and q.year = jan.year and 
       q.id2 = jan.id2 and q.element = jan.element)
 left join (select * from tblmonth 
            where groups='CCARE' and year=2016 and month='February') feb 
   on (q.groups = feb.groups and q.year = feb.year and 
       q.id2 = feb.id2 and q.element = feb.element);
```

Simply joining subqueries on the common fields.

The first subquery q isn't really crucial. 
Because you could use one of the months instead to join other months to it.
But the SQL looks better this way if one would add extra months.
Although it would make the SQL smaller.  For example:

```
select 
  jan.id2, jan.year, jan.groups, jan.element, 
  jan.month as jMonth, jan.budget as jBudget, jan.actual as jActual, jan.variance as jVariance, jan.[percent] as jPercent, jan.date_update as jDateUpdate,
  feb.month as fMonth, feb.budget as fBudget, feb.actual as fActual, feb.variance as fVariance, feb.[percent] as fPercent, feb.date_update as fDateUpdate
from tblmonth jan
left join tblmonth feb on (jan.groups = feb.groups and jan.year = feb.year and jan.id2 = feb.id2 
                           and jan.element = feb.element and feb.month = 'February')
where jan.groups='CCARE' and jan.year=2016 and jan.month='January';
```

Comment: It is 12 month * 4 column = 48 columns wrote by hand for just a year... And 12 joins in that case?

Comment: Of course, but it would be a lot of copy+paste and changing the month & aliases for those other months.  And since it wouldn't need EXEC there's no risk for SQL code injection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t1.id2, t1.budget,t1.actual,t1.variance,t1[percent]
,t2.budget,t2.actual,t2.variance,t2.[percent] 
from tblmonth t1 inner join 
 (select * from tblmonth where groups='CCARE' and month='February' ) t2
 on t1.id2 = t2.id2 and t1.year = t2.year
 where t1.groups='CCARE' and t1.month='January'
```